# django deployment using fabric - TypeError: prepare_deployment() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, django, fabric

I'm using this guide:
http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/

To set up my django project. But I'm stuck at deployment part.
I installed fabric using pip in my virtualenv.
I created this file inside myproject directory:

```
from fabric.api import local

def prepare_deployment(branch_name):
    local('python manage.py test finance')
    local('git add -p && git commit')
    local('git checkout master && git merge ' + branchname)

from fabric.api import lcd

def deploy():
    with lcd('home/andrius/djcode/myproject/'):
        local('git pull /home/andrius/djcode/dev/')
        local('python manage.py migrate finance')
        local('python manage.py test finance')
        local('/my/command/to/restart/webserver')
```

But when I enter this command (as shown in a guide):

> fab prepare_deployment

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 732, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 345, in execute
    results['<local-only>'] = task.run(*args, **new_kwargs)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 121, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: prepare_deployment() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

So even though it didn't specify in guide to enter argument, I suppose it requires my branch name. So entered this:

> fab prepare_deployment v0.1

(v0.1 is my branch name)
So now I got this error:

```
Warning: Command(s) not found:
    v0.1

Available commands:
    deploy
    prepare_deployment
```

Also I noticed in a guide for file fabfile.py in function prepare_deployment, input is written as 'branch_name' and inside function there is argument 'branchname'. So I thought it should be the same and renamed 'branchname' to 'branch_name', but still getting the same error.

So I think I'm doing something wrong here. What could be the problem?

Update:
I tried to call function inside fabfile.py with:

> prepare_deployment("v0.1")

Output was this:

```
[localhost] local: python manage.py test finance
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_finance', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Got an error recreating the test database: database "test_finance" does not exist


Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 2) while executing 'python manage.py test finance'

Aborting.
```

I think I should also mention that my app name is 'finance' as database name 'finance'. Maybe those are conflicting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fabric uses a specific syntax for passing arguments to tasks from the command line. From a bash shell you would need to use

```
fab prepare_deployment:v0.1
```

You can read about it in the [fabric documentation on per task arguments](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments).

If you ever actually need to use brackets in a bash command you would need to escape them.

Comment: It ran, but gave me error: Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database
Is there need some additional configurations for database connection when deploying?

Comment: can you run `python manage.py test finance` from the command line without errors?

Comment: No, gives the same error. I suppose database name and app name does not matter if its the same?
It gives error with all apps. So it for some reason do not have access to database.

Comment: There are lots of reasons why. It just sounds like the contents of settings.py is not correct. I would reccomend opening a new question and posting the database section of your settings.py.

Comment: Thanks I will. As your answer solved this error, so I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, this function should look like this...

```
def prepare_deployment(branch_name):
    local('python manage.py test finance')
    local('git add -p && git commit')
    local('git checkout master && git merge ' + branch_name)
```

Then you simply call...

```
fab prepare_deployment("v0.1")
```

Comment: This one gave me error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
But then I tried to just call function inside fabfile.py writing:
prepare_deployment("v0.1")